# Does every WinRT/Windows Core thread have a Dispatcher?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core, winrt-async

We're providing a library that needs to run code on its own custom threads. Once done, I want these threads to call callbacks (event handlers) through a `Dispatcher` (`System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`). The library user shall use the Dispatcher to dispatch event handling to.

We could simply always dispatch on `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` but not all programs (e.g. Windows 10 IoT Core apps) provide an UI and thus they lack a main window.

Can the user simply refer to [System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to get his thread's `Dispatcher`? Or can't all threads have a Dispatcher?

**Edit:** Here's more context for this question. Hopefully it makes the question easier to grasp: https://github.com/getsenic/nuimo-windows/issues/2

Comment: Why would you like to execute event handlers on UI thread? It is rather common case when some object raises events on background (non UI) thread. And user of your library must use Dispatcher to handle this events if he needs access UI elements in event handler.

Comment: The WPF behavior is rather unintuitive and got lots of programmers into trouble, many questions about it here.  WinRT did not repeat that mistake, you can only get a dispatcher from a window.  Which is the logical approach, a window can only work when it was created by a thread that has a dispatch loop, without that loop it is dead as a doornail.  If you don't have a window then you also no longer have the requirement to run code on a specific thread.

Comment: There is one method to raise events on UI thread. But it is required that your object was created/initialized from UI thread. Is it your case? I mean that it will work only in case when object was created from UI thread.

Comment: Or for example you could raise event handlers on the same thread it was subscribed, but it is not a simple solution.

Comment: I've updated the question to give more context.

Answer (score 1):

For first, I'm not sure, that you should execute event handlers on UI thread, because only client knows if he needed access UI elements.

For second, before invoking `CoreApplication.MainView` property you can check `CoreApplication.Views.Count > 0` (I'm not absolutely sure that it will work because currently I don't have device to test it).

And also you can solve this issue in another way: in constructor of you object save the SynchronizationContext of executing thread and then use it to raise events. It will work if your object instantiates from UI thread (in most cases it's true). That way you can completely refuse from Dispatcher.

```
public class NotifierExample
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;


    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;


    public NotifierExample()
    {
        _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }


    public void Do()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //do something
            OnSomethingHappened();
        });
    }


    private void OnSomethingHappened()
    {
        if (_synchronizationContext != null)
        {
            _synchronizationContext.Post(o => RaiseSomethingHappened(), null);
        }
        else
        {
            RaiseSomethingHappened();
        }
    }

    private void RaiseSomethingHappened()
    {
        var somethingHappened = SomethingHappened;
        somethingHappened?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't force the user to run handlers on UI thread. But the library needs to abstract from the fact that the library's events happen on a custom thread – it's just inconvenient if, as a library user, you have to synchronize all callbacks into your main thread to update UI (if any). Using `SynchronizationContext` looks great – will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

> Or can't all threads have a Dispatcher?

Dispatcher threads are always tied to UI threads. IoT headless mode app does not have an UI so it does not have a Dispatcher thread.

> Can the user simply refer to System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher to get his thread's Dispatcher

System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher is only supported in legacy .NET platform. The UWP alternative is CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher as you pointed out.

If you want to to do async callbacks in Headless(without GUI) mode, you can probably refer to Task Parallel Library(TPL), the ContinueWhenAll ContinueWhenAny etc API... might well suits your needs. Refer to  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.aspx.

Comment: Dear Jackie, thanks for your response. Unfortunately the Task is not started by the library user, it's rather started by the library at any point in time (it's actually a callback from a Bluetooth device). Although, it doesn't matter that a Task is involved since my question is about dispatching an `event Action` onto a thread where the user wants it to be dispatched to. Specifically it's about this issue here: https://github.com/getSenic/nuimo-windows/issues

Comment: @LarsBlumberg, are you considering using SynchronizationContext.Post? Depending on the headless mode, you can set the synchronization context to the UI or some none-UI thread.

Comment: Looks great! Where do get headless apps get their `SynchronizationContext` from?